# Lance-gg game socket.io failed to load resource on digital ocean

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, digital-ocean, lance

My lance-gg game works on localhost, but now that I have tried to deploy on digital ocean the site seems to be hosting but I can't connect the socket.io. The error in the client browser is:

`[Error] Failed to load resource: The request timed out. (socket.io, line 0) http://144.126.196.39:3001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NOU8Lc-`

The server code is:

```
import path from 'path';
import express from 'express';
import socketIO from 'socket.io';
import { Lib, ServerEngine, GameEngine } from 'lance-gg';

// define routes and socket
const server = express();
server.get('/', (req, res) => { res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html')); });
server.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/')));
let requestHandler = server.listen(3001);
const io = socketIO(requestHandler);

// Game Instances
const gameEngine = new GameEngine({ traceLevel: Lib.Trace.TRACE_NONE });
const serverEngine = new ServerEngine(io, gameEngine, { debug: {}, updateRate: 12 });
serverEngine.start();
```

And the client code is:

```
import { Renderer, GameEngine, ClientEngine } from 'lance-gg';

const options = {
    delayInputCount: 3,
    scheduler: 'render-schedule',
    syncOptions: {
        sync: 'extrapolate',
        remoteObjBending: 0.8,
        bendingIncrements: 12
    },
    serverURL: 'http://144.126.196.39:3001'
};

// create a client engine and a game engine
const gameEngine = new GameEngine(options);
const clientEngine = new ClientEngine(gameEngine, options, Renderer);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => clientEngine.start());
```

I understand the nodeJS starter template in digital ocean uses Nginx so I made sure to redirect using port 3001 to my app.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/moon-game-2;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name hellonode;

        location ^~ /assets/ {
                gzip_static on;
                expires 12h;
                add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        }

}
```

How can I make it so that my socket.io also connects to my lance-gg server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, solved my problem which was in the client code. On the cloud environment obviously, I don't need to specify the port 3001 like I do on localhost.

```
// ...

import { USE_CLOUD_SERVER } from './constants';
const options = {
    // ...

    // The cloud server is set up with Nginx to redirect to the right port.
    serverURL: USE_CLOUD_SERVER ? 'http://144.126.196.39' : 'http://localhost:3001'
};

// ...
```